# pyspark dynamically overwrite partition in s3 when write df

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark

let's say I have 3 partitions folders: year/month/day:

```
s3://bucket/table_name/Year=2022/month=march/day=04/file.parquet
s3://bucket/table_name/Year=2022/month=march/day=05/file.parquet
s3://bucket/table_name/Year=2022/month=june/day=01/file.parquet
s3://bucket/table_name/Year=2022/month=june/day=02/file.parquet
```

now the new batch is to load for year=2022, month=june, day=03, but I want to wipe the existing 2022/june/day 01 and day 02, then load

end result would be:

```
s3://bucket/table_name/Year=2022/month=march/day=04/file.parquet
s3://bucket/table_name/Year=2022/month=march/day=05/file.parquet
s3://bucket/table_name/Year=2022/month=june/day=03/file.parquet
```

```
#if I use 'dynamic' overwriteMode, this won't wipe the existing days for june. It will only do upsert. and if I use 'static' mode, it will wipe all existing partitions.

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode","dynamic"
output_df.write.partitionBy('year', 'month', 'day').mode("overwrite").parquet(write_parquet_location)


#2nd option would be manually delete the particular partitions first
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you delete the specific partitions you want to delete. How else would spark know which partitions to keep and to delete?

Comment: Option to delete by level 1 partition. Delete by level 2 partition etc? Maybe?  I’m here to ask